# Issue with replacing strings in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to replace a string with another one using `REPLACE()`, but I can't seem to make it work. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
<p>
<span style="font-size:14px;">
<img alt="" src="/content_images/CD-pin_1.gif"
```

I want to replace `src="/content_images` with `src="/public/userfiles/content_images` so I used this query: `UPDATE compudoc_informatie SET Tekst=REPLACE(Tekst, 'src="/content_images"', 'src="/public/userfiles/content_images"')` but it didn't work. Any ideas ?

Comment: Looks like you've closed the double-quotes when you shouldn't have. Try searching for `src="/content_images` (no trailing `"`) and replacing with `src="/public/userfiles/content_images` (again, no trailing `"`).

Comment: @Hobo Sapiens: Double quotes closes the html attribute value, the sql string is between single ones

Comment: @Denki: What error does the query give?

Comment: @Phate01 Yes indeed, but the OP is trying to replace only the first part of the attribute value. If he includes a trailing double-quote in his search string it won't match the next character of the target string, which is a `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've closed the double-quotes when you shouldn't have.

You're only replacing the first part of the `src` attribute so you should be searching for `src="/content_images` (no trailing ") and replacing with `src="/public/userfiles/content_images` (again, no trailing ").

What you're actually searching for is `src="/content_images"` (Note the trailing double quote) which won't match the target string `src="/content_images/` (trailing character is a `/`)

Your query should be:

```
UPDATE compudoc_informatie SET Tekst=REPLACE(Tekst, 'src="/content_images', 'src="/public/userfiles/content_images')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. One more question: how can I add a string at the beginning and end of multiple fields ?